# Data Alter & Transfer during Runtime between Three Classes

Tags: java, swing, class, variables, data-transfer

I makes three classes `DataTransfer, RetrieveData and StudSAllR` two classes `RetrieveData and StudSAllR` are `JFrame Form`

***DataTransfer Class:***

I have made a data member(Select) in DataTransfer class of variable integer and made two methods `getSelect()` and `setSelect(int Select1)`,the  code is given below:

```
class DataTransfer {
     int Select;
     public void setSelect(int Select1){
          Select=Select1;
     }
    public int getSelect(){
         return Select;
    }
}
```

***RetrieveData Class:***

In this class I have A two buttons `jButton2` and `jButton4`, under ActionListener of these two buttons both are making object of DataTransfer class and setting values by calling setSelect() method for set Select `0 & 1` 1 in jButton2 and 0 in jButton4 and after setting values both buttons are pointing to the third class StudSAllR, the below is its code given:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DataTransfer DT = new DataTransfer();
    DT.setSelect(0);
    System.out.println(DT.getSelect()+"RD");
    StudSAllR.main(new String[0]);
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DataTransfer DT = new DataTransfer();
    DT.setSelect(1);
    System.out.println(DT.getSelect()+"RD");
    StudSAllR.main(new String[0]);
}
```

***StudSAllR Class:***

Under this class also, I am making object of DataTransfer, now by calling getSelect method i m returning select value but,

The problem is that it returning only 0 value, either i press jButton2 or jButton4 it returns 0

I have also set `System.out.println(DT.getSelect()+"RD");` in the ActionListener of both buttons returns value  1 for jButton2 and 0 for jButton4

and when i call this get method in class 3 it returns only zero please guys help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the DataTransfer objects you construct in your action listeners for the buttons are local to those methods. Their lifetime is restricted to the scope of the method. If you want to use the set value in a different class, there are different ways.

1. Pass `DataTransfer` object into a method of other class `StudSAllR`, but then you cannot use `main()` because `main()` is supposed to accept only `String... args` so create a new static method probably called `processDataTransfer()`

   ```
   public static void processDataTransfer( String... args, DataTransfer dt )
   {

        int select = dt.getSelect();
   }
   ```
2. Make `Select` in `DataTransfer` static and also make `getSelect()` and `setSelect(int select)` static, then you don't need to initialize the class in button's action listeners. Just do : `DataTransfer.setSelect(1);`

In your `StudSAllR.main(String... args)` call `getSelect()` as :

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
  int select = DataTransfer.getSelect();
}
```

What to choose between 1, 2 really depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Help,Your second option works while being honestly I read your first option but as my java is week so, it was difficult for me to understand it, anyway your help works for me Thanks

Comment: In our mother tongue (URDU) we used to say the word  `CHEETAH` in English its `TIGER`  for the extra ordinary genius persons, for help i say u a CHEETAH